# Why is CAShapeLayer not centering to my UIView when I scale it?

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

```
 let centerPointX = colorSizeGuide.bounds.midX / 2
    let centerPointY = colorSizeGuide.bounds.midY / 2
    let circleWidth: CGFloat = 10
    let circleHeight: CGFloat = 10

    shape.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: centerPointX + circleWidth / 4, y: centerPointY + circleHeight / 4, width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight)).cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor(r: 160, g: 150, b: 180).cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor(r: 160, g: 150, b: 180).cgColor
    shape.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    shape.lineWidth = 0.1
    shape.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(4.0, 4.0, 1.0)
    colorSizeGuide.layer.addSublayer(shape)
```

Here's what's happening. I need the CAShapeLayer to stay in the middle of the small gray area:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggle with affine transforms a little myself, but here's what I think is going on:

The scale takes place centered around 0,0, so it will grow out from that point. That means it will "push away" from the origin.

In order to grow from the center, you should shift the origin to the center point of your shape, scale, and then shift the origin back, by the now-scaled amount:

```
var transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(centerPointX, centerPointY, 0)
transform = CATransformScale(transform, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0)
var transform = CATransform3DTranslate(
    transform,
    -4.0 * centerPointX, 
    -4.0 * centerPointY, 
    0)
shape.transform = transform
```

BTW, I can't make any sense of the image you posted with your question. You say "I need the CAShapeLayer to stay in the middle of the small gray area" I gather your shape layer is one of the circles, but it isn't clear what you mean by "the small gray area." It looks like there might be an outline that got cropped somehow.